# Java Connections netstat -ano

Tags: java, windows, networking, netstat

I am new to java and I have been testing my application all day long.

I just did

> netstat -ano

and it gave me a huge listing of active connections (listening, established) does this mean when i close my appliation these connections are not being shutdown (close())?

here is a screenshot:

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/9950/netor.jpg](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/9950/netor.jpg)

any advise on how to go about closing the connection when im done with it? i am trying to close the connection best to my knowledge but it appears im not doing enough.

thanks for your time.

EDIT: tcpview is great. yes those connections were earlier on the day when the code was not complete. now when i run it, it gets registered in tcpview and vanishes when i close the connection.

Comment: Netstat shows connections of all programs. Which port is your program using (either is listening or, or connecting to)?

Comment: Where's the evidence that those connections are due to java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netstat` is only of partial use for this sort of thing. Your output doesn't show which connections and ports are used by which process.

Download the [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) tool from microsoft, that'll show you clearly which process is using which ports, and which is maintaining open connections.

Comment: great tool. it officially verified my application is creating connections as needed and disposing them when i close! thanks a bunch for tcpview!